# All Handles disappeared vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I was working on a project and for no reason all Handles disappeared from the form

For example:

```
Private Sub Button17_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button17.Click
```

has become

```
Private Sub Button17_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

I have a lot of tools in the form
Is there a shortcut to retrieve Handles?

Comment: That you have a control named `Button17` is of grave concern. Start using meaningful names for your controls and everything else as well.

Comment: (a) If you look at the .designer.vb file for the problematic form, does it appear to be truncated? (b) You may be able to get some of your work back by using File History (assuming Windows 10). (c) You may be able to get some of your work back if you were using source control.

Comment: jmcilhinney Yes, I regret it now, but fortunately I know the necessary handle for each tool, it will only take a long time

Comment: Andrew Morton How do I use File History? i have windows 10

Comment: Key part of that comment: `if you were using source control.`

Comment: @DEVTE Press the Windows key. Start typing `file history` until something like "Restore your file with File History" appears. It does need setting up in the first place, and with a physically separate drive. It has saved "my" users a lot of repeated work when things go "oops!"

Answer (score 2):

This happens if a control is being cut and pasted back on the form or if it's deleted and recreated with the same name.

To recreate the `Handles` you can click behind the closing bracket and press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> - <kbd>TAB</kbd> - <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and fill the rest up with the help of IntelliSense.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not put the handle type in the right position

Comment: What do you mean by `does not put the handle type in the right position`?

Comment: Sorry my English is bad, I mean instead of putting a "timer" handle that puts a "button" handle

Comment: That's why I wrote `and fill the rest up with the help of IntellSense`. You won't get around some manual work unless you have a backup.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to retrieve. They are just regular methods now. You need to attach them to the appropriate events like you would any other method you wrote yourself. Open the Properties window in the designer and click the Events button. Select a control on the form, click the drop-down for the event of interest and select the correct method.