# How to find missing "handles" clauses in a vb.net project?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

We have a VS solution containing multiple VB projects. From time to time, some of the `Handles` clauses from procedure declarations get lost (which, for example, seems to happen when moving a control from one container to another one), causing non functioning buttons etc. in our software.

We're in the process to add an `AddHandlers()` sub to every class, in which we add the handlers manually, so `Handles` clauses will no be longer necessary. Until then, we have to keep an eye on those disappearing clauses.

Though we use Subversion, we don't always notice that a clause got lost.
Is there a we can have Visual Studio *automatically* check for missing `Handles` clauses? Maybe we could use some mighty black magic regex stuff for this task? Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Not really a solution to your question, but explains at least why they get lost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61730105/all-handles-disappeared-vb-net

Comment: Your "solution" is bad. Just don't cut and paste controls in the designer and there will be no issue. You can still drag and drop, just not cut and paste. There's never an issue if you just do the right thing.

Comment: As for finding places that a `Handles` clause may be missing, you could do a Find In Files for "sender As Object". That should list all event handlers and you'll be able to see in the list which do not have a `Handles` clause at the end of the declaration.